# Copiar intervalo de valores de um DataFrame para outro de forma transposta

Tags: python, pandas

Gostaria de copiar valores de vários intervalo em um df1 com 721 linhas e varias colunas, e colar em um df2 de forma transposta.

Algo como isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei algo como:

```
df1.T

 df2.iloc[0,1:18]=df1.iloc[0,0:17]

 df2
```

Mas não deu certo...

Comment: Dataframe e esse método `iloc` são do Pandas, não?!
Seria melhor adicionar a tag [tag:pandas] na pergunta para facilitar na pesquisa.

Comment: Mas o que vc quer fazer não é a `transposta` do `df` original? se for sua representacao esta errada, a transposta do `df` orginal teri que ter apenas 2 linhas e não 3.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]

col = ['col_'+str(i) for i in range(len(data[0]))]
row = ['row_'+str(i) for i in range(len(data))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col)
df.index = row
df
```

Resultado do dataframe `df`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Daí, você pode selecionar parte deste dataframe usando o `iloc`, por exemplo:

```
# df.iloc[seleciona linhas, seleciona colunas]
df2 = df.iloc[1:4,1:]
df2
```

Resultado do dataframe `df2`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então a transposta do dataframe `df2` é apenas fazer,

```
df2_T = df2.T
df2_T
```

Resultado da transposta do dataframe `df2`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]